# Game development equivalent of Movie Director

Tags: terminology, game-industry, career

Is there a job in game development that is equivalent to being a movie director?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it depends on the studio; there's no right or wrong answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Almo says, roles within game development vary quite widely from studio to studio, or sometimes even between projects for a single team. But there are common patterns.

I think the closest equivalent here would be termed a [Creative Director](http://getinmedia.com/careers/creative-director-games):

> The creative director is responsible for the overall vision of the
>   product: game play, visual style, story, audio assets, cinematics, and
>   marketing materials. This person is often the creator of the game
>   concept, and may serve as the primary designer. He or she works under
>   the supervision of the producer and is tasked with managing the teams
>   of artists, designers, and programmers, interacting directly with
>   senior supervisors of each department.